# Incrementing a Pointer to an Array within a structure

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I'm having a bit of trouble doing this and have searched High and low on the internet for help, but to no avail.
I'm basically trying to create a random matrix and print it out, I have a function `double random()` which works and has been tested and I have defined a structure as follows:

```
    typedef struct matrep {
         unsigned rows, columns;
         double *data;
    } MATRIX;
```

for which I have allocated memory properly, I use this and my random function to create a random matrix but what happens is the pointer never moves,

```
MATRIX *rand_matrix( MATRIX *mat ) 
{
    for ( int i=0; i < mat->rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j=0; j < mat->columns; j++ )
        {
             *(mat->data) = random() ;
        }
    }
    return mat ;
}
```

I know it never moves because when I print out the matrix using this function

```
void print_matrix(MATRIX *mat ) 
{
    int i, j ;
    if ( (mat->data)==0 || (mat->rows)==0 || (mat->columns)==0 )
    {
        printf("Empty matrix\n" );
        return ;       
    }
    printf( "\n\nMatrix of dimensions %d x %d\n\n", mat->rows, mat->columns) ;
    for ( i=0; i < mat->rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( j=0; j < mat->columns; j++ )
        {
            printf("\t%1.2lf", *(mat->data) );
        }
        printf("\n") ;
    }
}
```

and exchange random in the matrix above with 'j' it ends up printing out a matrix with the correct number of rows and collumns but each value is equal to the biggest value of j.

Basically what I was hoping you could help me with is figuring out how to increment my `*(mat->data)` pointer. I heard something about when you call the arrow operator it increments automatically but it doesnt seem to be working and when i try `*(mat->data)++` I get a nice big error.

Any help would be great thanks a million.

Comment: It doesn't increment automatically.

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually want to change `mat->data`; you need it to continue to point at your properly-allocated memory. Instead, you need to change this:

```
         *(mat->data) = random() ;
```

to something like this:

```
         mat->data[i * mat->columns + j] = random() ;
```

(to refer to the `i * mat->columns + j`th `double` in the memory-block pointed to by `mat->data`), and this:

```
      printf("\t%1.2lf", *(mat->data) );
```

to something like this:

```
      printf("\t%1.2lf", mat->data[i * mat->columns + j]);
```

(similarly).

> I heard something about when you call the arrow operator it increments automatically […]

This is not true, and I can't even think of anything similar that you might have heard, sorry.

---

**Edited to add:** Another approach, if you prefer, is to write something like this:

```
MATRIX *rand_matrix( MATRIX *mat ) 
{
    double *pTmp = mat->data;
    for ( int i=0; i < mat->rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j=0; j < mat->columns; j++ )
        {
             *(pTmp++) = random() ;
        }
    }
    return mat ;
}
```

which increments a pointer `pTmp` over all the elements. I don't know which approach is more clear. But either way, I don't think it's a good idea to modify `mat->data`.

Comment: Maybe he's thinking of the [`-->`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator) "goes to" operator.

Comment: Thanks very much, I tried the second way pTmp and it worked like a charm, I agree messing with mat->data probably wasn't helping but I'm wondering why adding an extra pointer into the mix makes a difference, surely its just pointing to the same place as before? Sorry if thats a stupid question but I really struggle with pointers

Comment: @Leavenotrace: Not a stupid question at all. The extra pointer makes a difference because it's safe to increment it. `pTmp` starts out just pointing to the same place as `mat->data`, but the `pTmp++` part moves it forward one space. (That's a "post-increment"; the statement `*(pTmp++) = random()` is equivalent to the statement `*pTmp = random()` followed by the statement `pTmp++`.)

Answer (score 0):

You should do mat->data++. (mat->data)++ is evaluating the value of mat->data and trying to increment it which is not possible.

Comment: even if I change the line *(mat->data) = random() to *(mat->data++) = random() I still end up with a matrix with every number the same only now they are all zeros

Comment: Don't try `*(mat->data)`, just increment the pointer by doing `mat->data++`

Answer (score 0):

Here: `printf("\t%1.2lf", *(mat->data) );' you're always pointing at the same memory.

You can use the `[]` operator to index and dereference a pointer, for example:

`(mat->data)[2]`

Answer (score 0):

Basically for storing a matrix using array, you need to allocate memory which closely mimics the 2D matrix, i.e. each and every matrix (or array) element should be accessed uniquely using different value for `rows` into `columns`.

You can do that in `C` in many ways. But the following is one of the most common way of doing the same. This lacks the de-allocation i.e. `free()`. Please try and do that yourself and we are here if you need any help!

NOTE: I can see multiple changes should be done in you code.. and so I'm attempting to provide a generic guidelines and reference as an answer!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        int row, column;
        int **matrix;
        int i, j, val;

        printf("Enter rows: ");
        scanf("%d", &row);
        printf("Enter columns: ");
        scanf("%d", &column);

        matrix = (int **) malloc (sizeof(int *) * row);
        for (i=0 ; i<row ; i++) 
                matrix[i] = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int) * column);

        val=1;
        for (i=0 ; i<row ; i++) {
                for (j=0 ; j<column; j++) {
                        matrix[i][j] = val++;
                }
        }

        for (i=0 ; i<row ; i++) {
                for (j=0 ; j<column; j++) {
                        printf("%3d  ", matrix[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }

        return 0;
}
```